# Read pixels from a rectangle in an OpenGL texture

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I know the `glGetTexImage` OpenGL function allows reading the pixels from an entire texture. Is there an OpenGL function that does the same thing but allows passing a rectangle to restrict the pixels read?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I ended up doing it in OpenTK (should translate easily to C++ or other OpenGL / OpenGL ES enabled languages):

```
public Bitmap GetBitmap()
{
    int fboId;
    GL.Ext.GenFramebuffers(1, out fboId);
    CheckGLError();
    GL.Ext.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, fboId);
    CheckGLError();
    GL.Ext.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0Ext, TextureTarget.Texture2D, TextureId, 0);
    CheckGLError();

    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
    var bits = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    GL.ReadPixels(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, Width, Height, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, bits.Scan0);
    GL.Ext.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, 0);
    GL.Ext.DeleteFramebuffers(1, ref fboId);
    b.UnlockBits(bits);

    return b;
}
```

Comment: FYI: I deleted my answer, as it was going into exactly the opposite direction.

Comment: Thanks for the help datenwolf, sounds like you know alot about OpenGL

Comment: I don't need the bitmap, just the RGB value at a particular co-ordinate, is this still the best approach?

Comment: Thanks jjktra, using `GL.ReadPixels(0, 0, 1, 1, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Rgba, PixelType.Int, ref Pixel);` I'm getting a value, 58950535, what is it's meaning?

Comment: I have a question here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36687524/opengl-access-rgb-pixel-data-in-a-stored-texture2d?noredirect=1#comment60967623_36687524, if you'd rather talk there.