# OpenGL - Access RGB pixel data in a stored Texture2D

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I've rendered the scene as solid colours to an FBO and stored it in a texture 2D, shown below.

[image]

Now I need to access the RGB values of a particular pixel co-ordinate, or texture-co-ordinate, either is helpful.

I understand I need to use `GL.ReadPixels` but have only succeeded creating a bitmap first and doing this every frame creates performance issues.

```
GL.Ext.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, FBO);
GL.Ext.FramebufferTexture2D(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, FramebufferAttachment.ColorAttachment0Ext, TextureTarget.Texture2D, Texture.GetTextureID("FBOtexture"), 0);

Bitmap b = new Bitmap(Width, Height);
var bits = b.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, Width, Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
GL.ReadPixels(0, 0, Width, Height, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgra, PixelType.UnsignedByte, bits.Scan0);
GL.Ext.BindFramebuffer(FramebufferTarget.FramebufferExt, 0);
b.UnlockBits(bits);
```

How can I access the data directly?

Comment: It's OpenTK, an OpenGL wrapper for C#.

Comment: so your code says soimething like `OpenTK GL = new OpenTK();`

Comment: To an extent I guess, what are you getting at? My entire engine is written with GL.* commands.

Comment: just wondering, was hoping it was something else so you could skip the bitmap copmpletely

Comment: http://www.opentk.com/node/1219

Comment: Why do you need to access the RGB values? If you are going to do more rendering with them, don't copy them back at all! Leave the texture sitting on the GPU and use it as a texture map for another render pass

Comment: It's for mouse picking. I've encoded object IDs in the RGB values of the FBO texture.

Comment: glReadPixels it is then. Remember that you don't have to read back the entire image, you can just use the x,y of the mouse coords and a width, height of 1,1

Comment: But even reading a 1x1 rectangle into a bitmap exhibits severe performance implications. I'm looking for a way to by pass the whole create bitmap, lockbits, write to bitmap, unlock bits approach. `GL.ReadPixels` can dump the read data to an int, byte, etc, but I'm unable to discern any meaning from the return.

Comment: http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, this is working

```
int pixelData = 0;

GL.ReadPixels (fboWidth / 2, fboHeight / 2, 1, 1, OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Rgb, PixelType.UnsignedByte, ref pixelData);

int red = Color.FromArgb(pixelData).R;
int green = Color.FromArgb(pixelData).G;
int blue = Color.FromArgb(pixelData).B;
```

But there *are* notable drawbacks.

As described in the [PBO](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html) article linked by j-p, `glReadPixels()` blocks the pipeline and waits until all pixel data is transferred, only then returning control to the application. In my program, and on my machine, that stall is noticeable.

The long term solution seems to be the Pixel Buffer Object which reduces the overhead by providing asynchronous data transfer between GL and the client. I'll amend this answer when I have something to show.